# scriptaculous effect occur once

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I have a button that makes a div move on the page, but I want for the button to make it move only once. If the user keeps clicking the button right now, the div keeps moving in the same direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and general way might be just setting a flag.

```
var box_can_move = true;
$('button_id').on('click', function(event, element){
    if(box_can_move){
        box_can_move = false;
        //move box;
    }
});
```

As alluded by clockworkgeek's comment, a big advantage of having a flag is being able to manipulate and inspect the state (of wether the box has already moved or not) directly without coupling it with the event handling logic.

Comment: This separates data (can the box move) from logic (a click event). A structured approach must be the smartest way of doing it and not dumb at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to use jQuery, this is simple with the `one()` method:

```
$('yourButtonId').one('click', 
    function(event) 
    { 
        alert('This will only execute once.'); 
    });
```

Comment: It works, but is there really no way within scriptaculous to do so? It kind of defeats the purpose of using it since this same effect can be achieved altogether using query

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
  $('button_id').on('click', function(event, element){
   new Effect.Move('div', {x: 300});
   element.stopObserving();
  });
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/pJ9cf/